# split data in a table into 2 columns based on conditions

Tags: sql, oracle

got to split a column in my table into 2 based on conditions.All in a select clause.

my table has a column as detail_code. There are 2 detail codes .I want each detail code as a separate column in my select clause.

I tried subquery but it throws subquery returns more than one row.

```
select id,(select detail_code from detc where type_ind ='C')as Detail_code1,
        (select detail_code from detc where type_ind ='P')as Detail_code2,
        (Select sum(amount) from amount_tbl where detail_code in (select detail_code from detc where type_ind ='C')and term_code='2019')as amt_detail_code1 
        from id_table;
```

My output should be

```
Id  Detail_code1  Detail_code2  sum(amt_Detail_Code1)  sum(amt_Detail_code2)
1          C                P                  15                  45
2          C                P                 785                  74
```

My input

```
ID     Detail_cd   ind  amt
317002687   CA20    C   3
317002687   CA21    C   60
317002687   CA23    C   18.75
317002687   CA25    C   179.64
317002687   CA26    C   136.5
317002687   CA27    C   8.25
317002687   CA28    C   4
317002687   CA2B    C   8
317002687   CA2H    C   6.75
317002687   CA2I    C   237
317002687   CA2J    C   65.4
```

Comment: It would help if you posted sample **input** data as well.

Comment: That's unreadable, I'm afraid. Please, post it properly formatted within the question itself (edit it).

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: Besides, what you posted doesn't match code (`select` statement) you wrote previously, so it is difficult to guess what you really want. If there was relation between source and target, it would be easier to assist. I suggest you give it another try; don't post information as if you don't want to be helped.

Comment: my input data has 4 columns (id,detail_code,ind,amt)                                                 
--what i want is id,detail_code1(all the detail_codes that has ind as 'C'),detail_code2(all the detail_codes that has ind as'P'),sum(amt_1) should be amount on all the all the detail_codes that has ind as'c' and finally the last column should have sum(amount) on  all the detail_codes that has ind as'P'

Comment: Which rows of your input table should be summarized in the first row of your output table, and which rows of your input table should be summarized in the second row of your output table?  (I.e., what do id 1 and 2 mean in the output table?)

Comment: Every ID can have detail_codes like (CA20,CA21..) for ind C as well as P. My first columns should be only ID,second column should be detail codes for ind 'C' ,3rd column should be detail codes for ind 'P'. So finally each ID should have only 1 row in the output.

Answer (score 0):

This query would produce the output you describe:

```
SELECT id, 'C' AS detail_code1, 'P' AS detail_code2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN ind = 'C' THEN amt END) AS sum_detail_code1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN ind = 'P' THEN amt END) AS sum_detail_code2
FROM name_of_your_input_table
GROUP BY id;
```

Alternatively, since you know what the two detail codes are, you could make those the column names and have the value of each column be the average for that detail code.  One way to do this is to pivot.  Here's the Oracle syntax:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT id, ind AS detail_code, amt
      FROM name_of_your_input_table)
PIVOT (AVG(amt)
       FOR detail_code IN ('C', 'P'));
```

Comment: Thank you... I applied a pivot on my detail codes and then a sum on the amount as 2 subqueries in my select .It worked